# Prove that $a_n$ converge for $|a_{n+1}-a_n| < \pi \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let sequence $a_n$ and let $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\pi \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^n $. Prove that the sequence converges.

I started with the given and written $-\pi \cdot{\left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^n}<a_{n+1}-a_n<\pi \cdot{\left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^n}$. Using sandwich we get that $a_{n+1}-a_n \to 0$.

Now, may I argue that for n large enough $a_{n+1}=a_n$? does it help?

How should I continue?

Comment: No, you need much more work to conclude. Hint: Show that, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$|a_{n+p}-a_n|<\varepsilon$$ whenever $n>N$ and $p>N$. Conclude that $\{a_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: What if $a_n = H_n$? Where $H_n$ denotes the harmonic numbers.

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: if you know something about convergence of series you could also do it by writing $a_{n+1} = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{i+1} - a_i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
For $m > n$,

$$
|a_m - a_n |
\le \sum_{i=n}^\infty \pi \left( \frac13 \right)^i
= \frac{3}{2} \pi \left( \frac13 \right)^n
$$